# What has replaced Application.CaptureScreenshot in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

My goal is to convert a block of text that is on the screen into an image and save it to the user's gallery (or downloads folder, or anywhere on there phone that allows them access to it)
On searching through the many many threads on this subject it seems the best way is to take a screenshot with the "camera". 
However, the manual tells me to use Application.CaptureScreenshot but in unity it says that is depreciated. 
All i can find on searching for alternatives are paid for assets (seems dodgy for something that should be so simple) and examples of using Application.CaptureScreenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot.html) is what you are looking for now.